# How can I fix the Insert/Edit link button in the Visual Editor in WordPress 3.9.1

Tags: visual-editor

I recently upgraded to WordPress 3.9.1 and now the "Insert/Edit" link button in the visual editor does not work when adding or editing a post.

There is no error in the javascript console and nothing actually happens when the button is pushed.  I have downgraded the site a version and still it does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas of what it can be?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by creating the link in a Word Processor document (Pages in my case) and then copy and paste into Wordpress. 
I had to edit the HTML text to open the webpage up in a separate window.

All working correctly now.